# Advanced writing for grouping two collections with java, such as using stream API or other advanced type?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two list, one is contain "category", the other is contain some more detail, such as:

```java
List<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<>(3);
categoryList.add("cat");
categoryList.add("dog");
categoryList.add("bull");
categoryList.add("other");

List<String> detailList = new ArrayList<>();
detailList.add("cat a");
detailList.add("cat b");
detailList.add("dog a");
detailList.add("dog b");
detailList.add("dog c");
detailList.add("bull a");
detailList.add("bird a");
detailList.add("bird b");

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String category : categoryList) {
    map.put(category,new ArrayList<>());
}

boolean isFind = false;
for (String detail : detailList) {
    isFind = false;
    for (String category : categoryList) {
        if (StrUtil.containsIgnoreCase(detail, category)) {
            map.get(category).add(detail);
            isFind = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isFind) {
        map.get("other").add(detail);
    }
}
    System.out.println(map);
```

The output is :
{other=[bird a, bird b], cat=[cat a, cat b], dog=[dog a, dog b, dog c], bull=[bull a]}

I use the loop ,but i wonder if there are some advanced way to do it? thanks.

Comment: Why not use a Map?

Comment: Your code fails if you have an entry with `caterpillar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

### `Collectors#groupingBy` and `List#contains`

Assuming your `details` and `categories` always have the same structure

```java
Map<String, List<String>> result = detailList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(detail -> {
            String category = detail.substring(0, detail.indexOf(' '));
            return categoryList.contains(category) ? category : "other";
        }));
```

However, `List#contains` performs poorely if the amount of data is high because it has a time complexity of `O(n)`. So I would advise to go for the next one

### `Collectors#groupingBy` and `Set#contains`

```java
HashSet<String> categories = new HashSet<>(categoryList);

Map<String, List<String>> result = detailList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(detail -> {
            String category = detail.substring(0, detail.indexOf(' '));
            return categories.contains(category) ? category : "other";
        }));
```

---

If you prefer looping however, instead of using the `Stream` API, you would want to look for something a bit more performant than what you have there.

Also, something a bit more robust.

Here are two problems I notice with your current code

- The time complexity is `O(m x n)` while it could be `O(m + n)` assuming both lists are sorted alphabetically
- You're using `String#contains` to identify whether a `detail` should be in one or the other category, possibly ending up having `catepillars` inside of the `cat` category